# Use ReStructuredText for pretty source code listing

Tags: html, restructuredtext

As is asked and answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716315/how-can-i-make-source-code-listing-block-in-html), one can use [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter) for pretty code listing.

With ReStructuredText, I can use raw directive as follows.

```
.. raw:: html

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCoreDefault.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">SyntaxHighlighter.all();</script>

I could use `SyntaxHighlighter <http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/>`_ for highlighting source code. 

.. raw:: html

    <pre class="brush: js;">
    function helloSyntaxHighlighter()
    {
        return "hi!";
    }
    </pre>
```

However, I need to have code directive that I can use.

```
.. code:: 

    function helloSyntaxHighlighter()
    {
        return "hi!";
    }
```

How can I translate code directive into the following HTML code?

```
<pre class="brush: js;">
function helloSyntaxHighlighter()
{
    return "hi!";
}
</pre>
```

Comment: As of docutils 0.9 you can just use the [code block](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#code) directive, which will automatically use the Pygments syntax highlighter if you specify the language - so no need for SyntaxHighlighter anymore!

Comment: @Chris,the code-block directive is fine unless the platform in question is like [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), which uses low-contrast black-on-purple pygments themes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way I have used:

- Install `rst2pdf` and `pygments`.
- Then make a copy of `rst2html`, call it `myrst2html` or whatever you want.
- In the copy, add this after the imports:

  ```
  from docutils.parsers.rst import directives 
  import rst2pdf.pygments_code_block_directive 
  directives.register_directive('code-block',
      rst2pdf.pygments_code_block_directive.code_block_directive)
  ```

And that's it, you now have the code-block directives.

Comment: Nice, this is helpful.  I've added what I did to get this to work [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14880062/319894).

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work as follows :

1. To generate `<pre>..</pre>`, I needed to modify ParsedLiteral, so I copied the ParsedLiteral class into Code as follows. Changing the line 5 `self.options['class'] = ['brush: js;'] # <--` is the main idea.

   class Code(Directive):

   ```
   option_spec = {'class': directives.class_option}
   has_content = True

   def run(self):
       self.options['class'] = ['brush: js;'] # <--
       set_classes(self.options)
       self.assert_has_content()
       text = '\n'.join(self.content)
       text_nodes, messages = self.state.inline_text(text, self.lineno)
       node = nodes.literal_block(text, '', *text_nodes, **self.options)
       node.line = self.content_offset + 1
       return [node] + messages
   ```
2. Add one line in **init**.py as follows.

   _directive_registry = {
         'code' : ('body', 'Code'),

Now, you can use the following code

```
.. code::

   print "Hello world!"  # *tricky* code
```

To get this HTML code

```
<pre class="brush: js; literal-block">
print &quot;Hello world!&quot;  # <em>tricky</em> code
</pre>
```

### Possible Easy Solution?

I could use ParsedLiteral if I find a way to pass the parameter of 'bruch: js;'. However, when I tried the code

```
.. parsed-literal::
   :class: "brunch: js;"

   print "Hello world!"  # *tricky* code
```

The tag becomes `<pre class="brunch ja">`.