# How can I get rst2html.py to include the CSS for syntax highlighting?

Tags: restructuredtext

When I run rst2html.py against my ReStructured Text source, with its code-block directive, it adds all the spans and classes to the bits of code in the HTML, but the CSS to actually colorize those spans is absent. Is it possible to get RST to add a CSS link or embed the CSS in the HTML file?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking: do you want to get syntax highlighting in your HTML output, or do you have the CSS to apply this syntax highlighting but don't know how to incorporate the custom CSS style into the build process?

Comment: I want syntax highlighting in the HTML output. The class attributes are all there (e.g. <span class="kt">), but there's no accompanying CSS being added by the build process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Docutils 0.9 you could use the [`code` directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#code). From the example on this page:

```
.. code:: python

 def my_function():
     "just a test"
     print 8/2
```

Alternatively, you can use Pygments for syntax highlighting. See [Using Pygments in ReST documents](http://pygments.org/docs/rstdirective/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5061604/623518) SO answer.

Finally, you could also use the code in [this](http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/restructuredtext-hscolour-and-pygments/) or [this](http://kupuguy.blogspot.co.uk/2008/05/blogging-with-docutils.html) blogpost.

**Update** As discussed in the comments, to get the style file used by Pygments use the command

```
pygmentize -S default -f html -a .highlight > style.css
```

which will generate the Pygments CSS style file `style.css`.

Comment: Yes, but there are no CSS styles for all the span classes that get added. How do I get the CSS?

Comment: I'm still not sure I exactly understand the question. Are you using Pygments or the `code` directive? If so the command `pygmentize -S default -f html -a .highlight > style.css` will generate the Pygments CSS style file `style.css`, which you then then use in your build process using the `--stylesheet` command (or similar) or `rst2html.py`.

Answer (score 5):

In docutils 0.9 and 0.10 it doesn't mattter whether you use code, code-block or sourcecode. All directives are considered [code role](http://repo.or.cz/w/docutils.git/blob/HEAD:/docutils/docutils/parsers/rst/languages/en.py).

This command will generate css that can embedded into html by rst2html.py.

```
pygmentize -S default -f html -a .code > syntax.css
```

This command will generate the html:

```
rst2html.py --stylesheet=syntax.css in.txt > out.html
```

By default, `rst2html.py` outputs spans with class names like `comment`, `number`, `integer`, and `operator`.  If you have a `docutils.conf` either in the same directory as the source, or `/etc`, or in `~/.docutils` with

```
[parsers]
[restructuredtext parser]
syntax_highlight=short
```

... then the class names will be `c`, `m`, `mi`, and `o` which matches `syntax.css` generated by `pygmentize`.

[See syntax-highlight in docutils documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/config.html#syntax-highlight)